# How get an element if its inner text matches a pattern in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, parsing

Consider a html like below,

```
<div id="test">
{{ sometext }}
</div>
<span class="testing">
{{ asdknfsdf }}
</span>
```

I want to get all the elements whose inner text matches `{{ <sometext> }}` in jquery. I tried the below code, but I could not get the elements properly. What am I missing here?

```
var elements = [];
$('*:contains("{{ .* }}")').each(function(){
   elements.push(this); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things:

1) "Could not get the elements properly" isn't terribly descriptive. Are you getting no results? Unexpected results?

2) By using a selector of `*:contains`, you are asking for every element that contains the specified text. That means you'll `html`, `body`, and other parent elements as well as the nearest `div`. Scope your selector to just `div` elements, or even better, to a class that you know might contain the expected result.

3) You can simplify your logic by simply calling `makeArray()` on the result of your selector:

```
var elements = $.makeArray($('body *:contains("{{ sometext }}")'));
console.log('elements ::', elements);
```

Comment: +1 , would advise to exclude the div out of div:contains so he will really get any type of element contains the string.

Comment: +1 for $.makeArray(). I am trying to get the immediate parent element which contains a text that matches a regex \\{\\{.*\\}\\} (java regex pattern)

Comment: See comment above regarding parent elements. Given your sample HTML, a selector of `*:contains` or `:contains` returns too much. It needs to be scoped more closely. See http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/. You need something else to qualify; or you need to do something more like @tilda's suggestion below.

Comment: +1 for `$.makeArray()` But instead of `div:contains`, goes `body *:contains`, doesn't it? Because you want to affect all elements, not just divs.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the :contains() selector in JQuery, and I don't think that it does regular expressions - you will have to make a regular expression and then loop through your elements to look for a match.  This is theoretical, but should get you started:

```
var reg = new RegExp("\{\{(.*)\}\}","g");
$('body *').each(function(i) {
   if(reg.test($(this)/text())) {
     //do something
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 var elements = [];
$('body *').each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=="{{ <sometext> }}"){
    elements.push($(this).html());
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7SdEv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery map function to test each element against a regular expression and return an array of elements:

```
var elements = $("*").map(function () {
    if (/{{.*}}/g.test($(this).text())) {
        return this;
    }
}).get();
```