# How to select middle nodes with specific text using jQuery :contains selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I want to get html elements containing specific text, and I used `:contains` selector. However, I'm not getting the nodes that I target.

In this example I'm trying to get all elements that has the 'today?' text, even if it's splited with other inline elements like `<a>`, `<span>`, `<sup>`, etc.

So I expect the result: DIV.some-class, P.another-class

```js
//let results = $(':contains(today?):not(:has(*))')
let results = $(":contains('today?')").not("script")


results.each(function() {
  console.log(`${this.tagName}${this.className ? '.' + this.className : ''}`)
})
/**
prints HTML, BODY, DIV.content, DIV.some-class, P.another-class
*/

console.log()



let results2 = $(":contains('today?')").not("script").children().filter(function() {
  return ($(this).text().indexOf("today?") > -1)
}).get()

results2.forEach(r => {
     console.log(`${r.tagName}${r.className ? '.' + r.className : ''}`)
})

/**
prints BODY, DIV.content, DIV.some-class, P.another-class
*/

console.log()

let results3 = $(":contains('today?')").not("script").filter(function() {
    return (
    $(this).clone() //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove() //remove all the children
    .end() //again go back to selected element
    .filter(":contains('today?')").length > 0)
}).get();

results3.forEach(r => {
     console.log(`${r.tagName}${r.className ? '.' + r.className : ''}`)
})

/**
prints P.another-class
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='some-class'>
    Hello world! How are you<a> doing today</a>?
  </div>
  <div class='some-other-class'>
    Bye world!
  </div>
  <p class='another-class'>
    Any <b>plans</b> for today?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You might get some ideas here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172170/how-get-an-element-if-its-inner-text-matches-a-pattern-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use children() and contains a selector. Here's a working solution:

```js
var elements = $('.content').children().filter(":contains('today?')");
var result = $.map(elements, function (el) {
      return `${el.tagName}${el.className ? '.' + el.className : ''}`;
 });

console.log(result.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='content'>
  <div class='some-class'>
    Hello world! How are you<a> doing today</a>?
  </div>
  <div class='some-other-class'>
    Bye world!
  </div>
  <p class='another-class'>
    Any <b>plans</b> for today?
  </p>
</div>
```